# max() function with joins not working properly - DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a query in which I am trying to find rows that contain maximum value in certain field. I tried max(field_name), but it returns all the rows.

```
SELECT CMNT.ID, MAX(CMNT.SEQ_NBR) AS SEQ, CMNT.VER_NBR AS VERSION 
FROM 
CUSTOMER_CMNT AS CMNT
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_PROD AS PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = CMNT.BALE_ID 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_LOAN LOAN ON (PRODUCT.LOAN_ID = LOAN.LOAN_ID) AND (PRODUCT.START_YR = LOAN.START_YR) AND (PRODUCT.ST_CD = LOAN.ST_CD) AND (PRODUCT.CNTY_CD = LOAN.CNTY_CD)
WHERE CMNT.ID > 0 AND PRODUCT.START_YR = 2013 AND LOAN.LOAN_NBR = 17124
GROUP BY CMNT.VER_NBR, CMNT.SEQ_NBR, CMNT.ID, CMNT.CMNT_TXT
```

output

```
+----------------+------+---------+
| CMNT.ID        | SEQ  | VERSION |
+----------------+------+---------+
 133340000101373   2       1
 133340000101374   2       1
 133340000101373   3       1
 133340000101374   3       1
 133340000101373   4       1
 133340000101374   4       1
 133340000101373   1       2
 133340000101374   1       2
 133340000101373   1       3
 133340000101374   1       3
 133340000101373   2       3
 133340000101374   2       3
```

But, the expected rows are (max(SEQ_NBR) ):

```
+----------------+------+---------+
| CMNT.ID        | SEQ  | VERSION |
+----------------+------+---------+
 133340000101373   4       1
 133340000101374   4       1
```

However I modified the query as below that returns the above expected result.

```
SELECT CMNT.ID, MAX(CMNT.SEQ_NBR) AS SEQ, CMNT.VER_NBR AS VERSION 
FROM 
CUSTOMER_CMNT AS CMNT
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_PROD AS PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = CMNT.BALE_ID 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_LOAN LOAN ON (PRODUCT.LOAN_ID = LOAN.LOAN_ID) AND (PRODUCT.START_YR = LOAN.START_YR) AND (PRODUCT.ST_CD = LOAN.ST_CD) AND (PRODUCT.CNTY_CD = LOAN.CNTY_CD)
WHERE CMNT.ID > 0 AND PRODUCT.START_YR = 2013 AND LOAN.LOAN_NBR = 17124
CMNT.SEQ_NBR = (select max(CMNT.SEQ_NBR) from   
FROM 
CUSTOMER_CMNT AS CMNT
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_PROD AS PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = CMNT.BALE_ID 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_LOAN LOAN ON (PRODUCT.LOAN_ID = LOAN.LOAN_ID) AND (PRODUCT.START_YR = LOAN.START_YR) AND (PRODUCT.ST_CD = LOAN.ST_CD) AND (PRODUCT.CNTY_CD = LOAN.CNTY_CD)
WHERE CMNT.ID > 0 AND PRODUCT.START_YR = 2013 AND LOAN.LOAN_NBR = 17124)
```

Due to subquery, this query went bit longer. Is there a way to shorten/improve this query ?

Comment: Likely unrelated to the JOINs. The first query groups by more than is desirable to effect the desired aggregate; the same result would be if all JOIN criteria removed and just the CMNT file were queried. The second query is not syntactically correct nor is that query likely to produce the *correct* results even if the scalar subselect were as-coded but properly as an ANDed predicate. Seems probable, the sample data merely _happens to_ produce the expected output; effectively by chance, rather than by intent; lacking a GROUP BY, the subselect selects the MAX(SEQ_NBR) irrespective anything else.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Not sure if it performs better though...

```
declare @data table (cmnt_id bigint, seq int, version int)

insert into @data
values (133340000101373, 2, 1), (133340000101374, 2, 1), (133340000101373, 3, 1), (133340000101374, 3, 1), (133340000101373, 4, 1), (133340000101374, 4, 1), (133340000101373, 1, 2), (133340000101374, 1, 2), (133340000101373, 1, 3), (133340000101374, 1, 3), (133340000101373, 2, 3), (133340000101374, 2, 3)

select d.cmnt_id, d.seq, d.version
from @data d
inner join (
    select cmnt_id, max(seq) as target_seq
    from @data
    group by cmnt_id
    ) x on x.cmnt_id = d.cmnt_id
    and d.seq = x.target_seq
order by d.cmnt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you cold run your query through the Visual Explain tool, and it will recommend indexes that it believes are missing.

Outside of that, I'd definitely recommend the following indexes / keyes:

```
CUSTOMER_CMNT
   index1 => BALE_ID
   index2 => ID, SEQ_NBR

CUSTOMER_PROD
   index1 => START_YR
   index2 => LOAN_ID, START_YR, ST_CD, CNTY_CD

CUSTOMER_LOAN
   index1 => LOAN_NBR
   index2 => LOAN_ID, START_YR, ST_CD, CNTY_CD
```

HTH!